# Domain Access and Domain Admin giving access to all subdomains

Tags: multi-sites, domain-access

I've set up a multisite drupal 7 install with domain access and each subsite has an assigned admin who is only supposed to see content and edit own domain. I want to allow each domain admin to also change theme of the subdomain by going to Structure->Domain->Click on edit domain of own domain -> Theme tab

I am able to do this, however, the subdomain admin is able to see all subdomains under Structure->Domains, I only want to allow him to view only the assigned subdomain.

i've been playing around with permissions but can't seem to get this working. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: Create a custom module and add validation there